# Rails - correct way to refer model instance to second model instance by console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails application contains two models named customer and order

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name
    end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

In the console I created instance to the customer model:

```
c=Customer.new(:name=>"Noa")
```

Now I want to create instance to order model which refer to "c"
How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to have a `has_many` inside the `Customer` class:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name
   has_many :orders
end
```

and then you can do the following to associate a new order to your customer.

```
order = c.orders.build :attribute => 'value', # ...
```

You could find [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference) more details about how to build associations between object in Rails.